# MongoDB query collection by custom key and return nested objects with limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to query a MongoDB Collection of nested objects, any gurus care to share the knowledge?

Will explain with a simplified example.

Get the last two objects from the "loc" array where "uuid" is equal to 16.

Any help much appreciated.

Example collection:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5a4f1ff0fc6ded723265e6b0"),
   "uuid":"15",
   "location_history":{  
      "loc":[  
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         },
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         },
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         }
      ]
   }
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("3a4f1ff0fc55ed723265e6b0"),
   "uuid":"16",
   "location_history":{  
      "loc":[  
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         },
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         },
         {  
            //remove for demo sake
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoe can use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/index.html) with value `-2` as a projection to get the last two documents from nested array.

```
db.collection.find({ "uuid": "16" }, { "location_history.loc": { $slice: -2 } })
```